# access CLI for cordova in visual studio project

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, visual-studio-cordova

I'm installing Apache cordova tools for visual studio 2017 and creating a new project, now i want to use cordova commands like adding platform or plugin etc.
I know i can use several other ways to achieve these but i want to know is there a way to access CLI for cordova in visual studio?

Comment: Have you looked at this link here [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2014/12/17/build-and-run-using-cordova-cli]

Comment: @Toxide82 yes, but there isn't anything about accessing to CLI directly from VS

Answer (score 1):

> I know i can use several other ways to achieve these but i want to know is there a way to access CLI for cordova in visual studio?

As far as I know, currently there is no way to access CLI for cordova in visual studio.

You can use other extensions of Visual Studio like [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) to popup a cmd window from your project.

Comment: this is correct, i installed cordova and nodejs with visual studio installer, i have both in visual studio but i can't access them in cmd, "node" and "cordova" is not recognizable as a command.